# Android two way data binding with float MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I need two way data binding from EditText to MutableLiveData.
One way work fine, from LiveData to View:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:dtm")
fun AppCompatEditText.conversion(value: Float) {
Log.d("DTAG","Find")
setText(value.toString())
}
```

But the other way, from EditText to MutableLiveData I cant set:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:dtm", event = 
"android:textAttrChanged")
fun AppCompatEditText.conversion(): Float {
Log.d("DTAG","John Connor")
return this.text.toString().toFloat()
}
```

It cause loop between the two binding adapters

**What am I doing wrong?**

My Variable:

```
var a1CValue = MutableLiveData(7.0f)
```

View:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/firstText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            app:dtm="@={dataModel.a1CValue}"
            tools:text="1.2" />
```